# Static mocking with PowerMock and Mockito not working

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to verify that the Collections.shuffle() method was called in one of my classes. I read through the (little) documentation on PowerMock with Mockito and read through the other SO questions that dealt with this issue and didn't get a resolution.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Collections.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void testShuffle() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Collections.class);
        PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(Collections.class);
        Collections.shuffle(Mockito.anyListOf(Something.class));

        ClassToTest test = new ClassToTest();
        test.doSomething();

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(); // Verify shuffle was called exactly once
        Collections.shuffle(Mockito.anyListOf(Something.class));
    }
}

public class ClassToTest {
    private final List<Something> list;
    // ...
    public void doSomething() {
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        // do more stuff
    }
}
```

Given the above code, I expect the unit test pass. However, the unit test fails as follows:

```
Wanted but not invoked java.util.Collections.shuffle([]);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
As per the suggestion below I tried the following, and I get the same error.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Collections.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void testShuffle() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Collections.class);

        ClassToTest test = new ClassToTest();
        test.doSomething();

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(); // Verify shuffle was called exactly once
        Collections.shuffle(Mockito.anyListOf(Something.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you loosen the restriction on your matcher from `anyListOf` to `any(List.class)`? What happens if you add `ClassToTest` to the `@PrepareForTest` annotation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a rather old question, but I'd still like to clarify that the accepted answer is in fact incorrect. By executing the following code,

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Collections.class);
Collections.shuffle(Mockito.anyListOf(Something.class));
```

all verifies will always pass afterwards:

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(); // Verify shuffle was called exactly once
Collections.shuffle(Mockito.anyListOf(Something.class));
```

even if you do not call `test.doSomething();` the provided test in the answer will still pass. The correct way to test this is to actually check if the items in the List have been sorted correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I was probably doing something dumb due to inexperience back then. I completely agree that it's best to test public contracts as opposed to internal implementation details.

Answer (score 4):

You can either mock/verify the java.util.Collections.shuffle([]) method or call the real implementation (with PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod()). But you can't do both.

If you remove

```
PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(Collections.class);
```

the call will be verified and the test will pass.

https://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.4.7/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#doCallRealMethod%28%29

This code works for me:

```
package test;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Collections.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void testShuffle() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Collections.class);
/*        PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(Collections.class);  remove this line */
        Collections.shuffle(Mockito.anyListOf(Something.class));

        ClassToTest test = new ClassToTest();
        test.doSomething();

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(); // Verify shuffle was called exactly once
        Collections.shuffle(Mockito.anyListOf(Something.class));
    }
}

class ClassToTest {
    private List<Something> list = new LinkedList<Something>();
    // ...
    public void doSomething() {
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        // do more stuff
    }
}
class Something {
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and my test still fails saying that there were zero interactions with the mock. See my edit.

Comment: Ah thank you... I missed the part where I have to call Collections.shuffle()... Although I could have sworn I tried that also.